# How to test a scheduler class scheduling itself and calling a batch. Check out the code

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

I have a batch class which is called by an scheduler class which is scheduling itself. I have written a test class which has two methods: One tests the batch and the other the scheduler.Overall the test passed and the batch class code coverage is good and the scheduler class's second method(execute method) is also covered in test class but the first method which is there to schedule itself is not getting covered. Please help.
My scheduler class code:

```
global class ContUpdateScheduler implements Schedulable{
    global static String cronExp = '0 0 13 * * ? *';
    **This method is not getting covered**
    global static String scheduleMe(){
        ContUpdateScheduler scheduler = new ContUpdateScheduler();
        return System.schedule('Update Contacts', cronExp, scheduler);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        ContactUpdateBatch batchable = new ContactUpdateBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(batchable, 100);
    }
}
```

My testclassmethod for testing the scheduler:

```
@istest
    public static void testSchedule() {
        String sch = '0 0 13 * * ? *';
        ContUpdateScheduler testsche = new ContUpdateScheduler();
        //string fetchID = testsche.scheduleMe();
        Test.StartTest();
        string JobId = system.schedule('Test status Check', sch, testsche );
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Comment: The method you want to test is commented out in your test class.

Comment: @SebastianKessel- I commented it as this line was giving me error:
Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: String 
If this error would not have appeared I was thinking of adding these two lines:
string ID = [SELECT Id, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ID = :JobId ];
 system.assertEquals(ID,fetchID);

Comment: You were just calling it incorrectly, and that was your real error. @sfdcfox already posted the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your unit test needs to call the method:

```
@isTest static void testScheduleMe() {
  Test.startTest();
  ContUpdateScheduler.scheduleMe();
  Test.stopTest();
}
```

Coincidentally, this will cover the execute method as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem in a jiffy and I was trying and googling it for so long. Silly me!! calling an static method in this way..

Comment: Unit test with no assertions. >:(

Comment: @AdrianLarson tbh, I prefer "only as much assertion as necessary." In this case, if the schedule call fails, an exception is thrown and the test fails. No assertion is strictly necessary. I know others have differing opinions, but I've always been a minimalist with coding.

Comment: I guess it depends on the purpose of the test. If it is to test that scheduleMe doesn't throw an exception that's fine. But if it wants to check that scheduleMe schedules execution, which in turn calls execute, then some assertions are warranted.